# launch the gui chromium using puppeteer with the same tabs

Tags: node.js, screen-scraping, puppeteer, chromium

I'm looking for a way to open a website in puppeteer and do some processing then at some point open the installed chrome/chromium with gui and continue the job on the real chromium with the existing tabs that were opened in puppeteer.

Comment: sorry if i explained it not so good

Comment: What purpose do you want to achieve by doing these?

Comment: Maybe you can create a browser tab, close the browser, then initialize the browser tab again. Puppeteer running twice with different `headless` option.

The first `await puppeteer.launch({headless: true})` then run your processing, then close it `await browser.close()`. Then continue with launching the second with `await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})`.

It's simpler than make your puppeteer crash. :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a browser tab, close the browser, then initialize the browser tab again. Puppeteer running twice with different headless option.

```
// The first
await puppeteer.launch({headless: true})
.
.
.
// then run your processing
await page.pdf({path: 'print.pdf'})
.
.
.
// then close it
await browser.close()
.
.
.
// Then continue with launching the second with
await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
```

It's simpler than make your puppeteer crash. :D

Answer (score -1):

For this to work, Chromium and Chrome should use the same profile. You need to create a separate profile with a particular setting so when you relaunch Chrome it starts from where you left off. You can do it from Chrome and then pass it to puppeteer or create it with Puppeteer. Here is my suggestion:

1. Create a program that opens chromium with puppeteer, without visiting any website, and set enough delay so you can change settings manually (e.g. `page.waitFor(60000)` before closing the browser).
2. Create a directory and pass it to the `userDataDir` as the launch option:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, userDataDir:"path/to/directory"});
```

3. Run the program. When it launches chromium, go to `Settings -> On startup` and set the option to `Continue where you left off`
4. Now the profile is *initialized*. Launch your puppeteer program with the `userDataDir` option pointed to the profile directory. When you're done with your stuff with chromium, relaunch it with Chrome and the same profile in `userDataDir`, it should continue with all open tabs where you left off.